# Laravel AJAX create HTML DOM(tooltip) element onhover

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

How to create dynamically tooltip using AJAX in Laravel?

I've got table, each element of table has it own ID, stored in `<div id="[numbers]" hover="tooltip(this.id);"></div>`

For each element I want to "create" or display tooltip(for displaying data like `name`, `date`, etc.).

Is it possible? This is what I've got at the moment:

```
 // blade.view
        function test(id)
        {
            $.ajax({{ 
                type: "GET",
                data:
                {
                  id:id,
                },
                url: "{{ route('box.getData') }}",
                success: function(data){
                    alert("data");
                }
             }});
        }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/box', 'App\Http\Controllers\BoxController@getData')->name('box.getData');
```

How to proceed with that in Controller?

Added controller:

```
public function getData(Request $request)
{
    $absence = Absence::findOrFail($request->id);

    return response()->json($absence, 200);
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the current code? Why do you need AJAX code to create a tooltip?

Comment: Exectly I'm not familiar with Ajax. I've got a little bit complicated page with an attendance calendar. I've got `div` in each table cell for each day in month. I was trying to do it without the AJAX, but the variable was overwritten by latest value, even if I was 'emptying' it after use it didn't help. Now my logic can't be modyfied so I need to use dynamic tooltip displaying

Comment: I've added the controller code and edited view. For now it's returning the data, but I need to know how to pass/display/catch it in view f.e. specific fields like `$absence->reasons->name;`

Comment: If you want to use data in a view, why not add it there as usual data, without AJAX?

Comment: Because I iterate through all days in month, then foreach attendance I check if day of month is betweeen attendance start and end. But it's overwritting eitherway for latest attendance data even emptying.